# Where is the "raw query" search option in the "New Outlook" for Mac interface (O365)

Tags: mac, ms-office, search

I'm using a work machine (Catalina) with an Office 365 subscription and gave the "New Outlook" toggle (Outlook 16.45) a go, however, I'm not finding any of the "advanced" search options that are in the old interface, specifically, "raw query".

I'm giving MSFT the benefit of the doubt that they didn't just follow the "release a redesign missing half the old features" paradigm and that I'm an idiot.  Where is that functionality in "New Outlook"

New Interface:

[image]

Old Interface:

[image]

I'll note that I have seen this question, but it answers for the "olde" interface:
[How can I search for meeting invites in Microsoft Outlook for Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381600/how-can-i-search-for-meeting-invites-in-microsoft-outlook-for-mac)